# Example of a ring such that $R^2\simeq R^3$, but $R\not\simeq R^2$ (as $R$-modules)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

The usual example of unitary ring without the [IBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number) property is the ring of column finite matrices, and in this case we have $R\simeq R^2$ as (left) $R$-modules. (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265300/a-ring-without-the-invariant-basis-number-property).) In particular, we have $R^2\simeq R^3$.

> I wonder if there is an example of unitary ring (without the IBN property) such that $R^2\simeq R^3$, but $R\not\simeq R^2$ (as $R$-modules).

Comment: Reltated: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/335299

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only other examples of non IBN rings that I am aware of are built using Leavitt path algebras, and they do exactly what you want. It is possible to specify positive integers $n<m$ such that $R^i\ncong R^j$ for $(i,j)$ less than $(n,m)$ in the lexicographic order, but $R^n\cong R^m$ as modules. (The $(m,n)$ pair is called the 'module type' in the Leavitt article.)

Unfortunately, it is a bit unwieldy to reproduce the entire construction here. [Here](http://www.uccs.edu/~gabrams/documents/AbAnhPardoversionwhichappearedcrelle624Nov2008.pdf) is one paper discussing the construction.

I think the other Abrams reference in the wiki article on IBN must be useful as well (I was the one who put the citation up, but I was a long time ago.)

[Here](http://imath.kiev.ua/~kay/pdf/lectures/cordoba/ara.pdf) is another article that addresses it much more directly. It cites Leavitt's original result which is what I'm describing (theorem 1.3.3)

For everyone's enjoyment, here's the citation for Leavitt's article:

> W. G. Leavitt. [The module type of a ring](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1962-103-01/S0002-9947-1962-0132764-X/S0002-9947-1962-0132764-X.pdf). Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 103: 113–130, 1962.