# Commutative Ring where $R \times R \not\cong R$ but $R \times R \times R \cong R \times R$ as rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

For a commutative ring with unity, I can find a nontrivial ring $R$ such that $R \times R \cong R$ as rings. For example you can just take $R = \prod_{n=1}^\infty A$ where $A$ is any nonzero ring. Is there an example of a ring where $R \times R \not\cong R$, but $R \times R \times R \cong R \times R$? Or is there a reason such a ring cannot exist?
Here all the isomorphisms I'm considering are as rings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of a ring such that $R^2\simeq R^3$, but $R\not\simeq R^2$ (as $R$-modules)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605819/example-of-a-ring-such-that-r2-simeq-r3-but-r-not-simeq-r2-as-r-modul)

Comment: As rings, or as $R$-modules?

Comment: I'm looking for as rings

Comment: Please put all the information on the post, not just in the comments.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869512/does-a2-cong-b2-imply-a-cong-b-for-rings  (In particular, any answer to this question gives an answer to that question with $A=R$ and $B=R^2$.)