# Examples of modules $M$ such that $M^r \cong_R M^s \iff \exists A \in \mathcal A \; r,s \in A$, where $\mathcal A$ is a partition of $\mathbb N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, examples-counterexamples

Let $\mathcal A$ be a partition of $\mathbb N := \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. I would like to know:

> Is there an example of a ring $R$ and an $R$-module $M$ such that $M^r$ is isomorphic to $M^s$ as left $R$-modules if and only if $r$ and $s$ are in the same set of $\mathcal A$, i.e. 
>   $$M^r \cong_R M^s \iff \exists A \in \mathcal A \; r,s \in A$$

We can find a related [question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3). Examples with $M=R$ or $R = \Bbb Z$ are particularly welcome. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335299/given-n-in-mathbb-n-is-there-a-free-module-with-a-basis-of-size-m-foral) can also be related. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1606360) answer provides a very good example.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Here $M^r$ denotes the direct sum (or direct product), not the tensor product. Another interesting question would be to replace $M^r$ by $M \oplus \Bbb Z^r$ (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218113).

Comment: Interesting theorem of Leavitt cited here : http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1969-75-01/S0002-9904-1969-12150-6/S0002-9904-1969-12150-6.pdf

Comment: This answer has an interesting reference: https://mathoverflow.net/q/10194