# What are some examples of free modules that have 2 bases of different sizes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples, free-modules

If M is a free module over a commutative ring, then any 2 bases for M will have the same cardinality. I'm looking for an example of a module that **doesn't** have this property, as well as examples of the bases in question.

Comment: A free module and a module with a basis are the same thing. So, if a module doesn't have the property you have written, then it simply doesn't have a basis at all.

Comment: @wgrenard no, I'm not looking for a free module without a basis, I'm looking for a free module with, for example, a basis A and a basis B where $\abs{A} ≠ \abs{B} $

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Good question!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335299/given-n-in-mathbb-n-is-there-a-free-module-with-a-basis-of-size-m-foral

Comment: Update: I've found one on my own, but I don't know how to type matrices in Latex, so I will post it later when I've learned

Comment: The duplicate I linked mentions the only two families of examples I know of: using the endomorphism ring of infinte dimensional vector spaces, and using Leavitt path algebras.

Comment: @rschwieb respectfully, I don't think this is a duplicate, as this one seems more concrete. Also that one is extremely difficult to understand (or even find) for someone like me who is just starting to learn about algebra. I've found a very simple example that is easy to understand that I was planning on posting here. Is there some way you could reopen this question?

Comment: @ZacharyF The Leavitt-path solution is a bit complex... but you should follow the second link in the post to read the simpler example of the linear transformations. I don't see how this is any more concrete than either of those posts. If you are having a specific difficulty with one of the answers you can ask at the post, or else formulate a new post about what is blocking you. I'm happy to help you here or there.

Comment: @ZacharyF Could you comment on your "extremely simple example"? I'm unaware of a simpler example than the ring of linear transformations of an infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: @rschwieb sure. The example I found is the ring of 2x2 matrices taken as a module over itself. It has a basis of 1 element, namely the identity matrix. It also has a basis of 2 elements which is a little harder for me to describe without mathjax, namely the matrices with zeroes everywhere except for a 1 in the top corner (one has it in the left corner and the other has it in the right corner)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68543/discussion-between-rschwieb-and-zachary-f).