# Can a free module have invariant basis number if its ring doesn't?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules, invariance

Is there a free $R$-module $M$ such that $M$ has invariant basis number (IBN), while $R$ does not have the [IBN property](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Invariant_basis_number)?

My use of "invariant basis number" here (for modules) doesn't seem to be standard, but I just mean $M$ has a unique, well-defined rank. To rephrase my question, can there exist a free $R$-module $M$ such that

1. Every basis of $M$ has the same cardinality.
2. There exists a free $R$-module that has bases of different cardinalities.

---

Just curious, as I'm only first learning about IBN and don't know many examples yet.

Comment: What about $M=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I mention in passing the zero module, which is free and with a unique number of generators for any ring, but it is not really in the spirit of the question.)

Using Leavitt path algebras, it is possible to construct a ring such that $R^2\cong R^3$, and hence $R^2\cong R^n$ for all $n\geq 2$, but $R\ncong R^2$. ([Here is another post about it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335299/given-n-in-mathbb-n-is-there-a-free-module-with-a-basis-of-size-m-foral/335395#335395))

In that case, every cyclic free $R$ module has a unique rank, but free modules with more than one generator do *not*.

You're right that one shouldn't probably call this "invariant basis number for a module" but rather say that it's a free module "whose bases have a unique, finite size" or something like what you said.

Comment: So am I correct that in this example, $R$ is a free module over itself with rank 1?

Comment: Yes, the only one with rank $1$, up to isomorphism.  And all free modules with more generators do not have a unique rank.